# How to penalize False Negatives more than False Positives in PyTorch BCEWithLogitsLoss

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I have a dataset containing text sequences with corresponding labels (0 or 1). The issue is that the dataset has approx. 20x more sequences with label 0 than with label 1. I encountered a method to improve the FNR, namely to weigh FNs heavier than FPs in the loss function. However, with the loss function I use (PyTorch BCEWithLogitsLoss) this isn't an option as far as I could see. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Isn't this the exact purpose of the `pos_weight` argument for `BCEWithLogitsLoss`? (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) Basically you want label `1` to have higher weight than label `0`.

Comment: I feel incredibly dumb now.. I've been looking for half an hour and it was right in front of me the entire time. Thank you!

Comment: Easy to miss parts of documentation, happens to everyone!